# SQL - Find Date in Range that is same day as another Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, dayofweek

I'm looking for a solution in SQL.

Assume I have a source date, say `08/28/2018` (which is a Tuesday).  I also have a date range beginning `09/17/2018` and ending on `09/23/2018`.

How do I find the date for same day as the source date.  The answer should be `09/18/2018`.

Just not sure how to do this with SQL.

(I'm hitting other tables, just need to get this little bit).

Thanks.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Tagged with `sql-server` based on the answer given

Comment: Is the searched timespan always seven days long? And always monday to sunday?

Answer (score 0):

So solve this I used the following query...

```
select dateadd(day, datepart(dw, '08/28/2018')-2, '09/17/2018')
```

Now, I can parameterize this and it will work fine.